# Server Type Option missing While Installation SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, installation

I am having a machine installed with `windows server 2012 standard` with `Sql server 2008 with sp1`.

While installing SharePoint I see "`Installation Type(Farm and Standalone)`" missing.

Can any one help me how can I solve this?